# Python for OR: Which non-solver libraries do you use?

Tags: python

If you're programming OR challenges in Python, besides using mathematical optimization software (= constraint solvers), which other libraries do you often use? Maybe for mundane tasks such as data parsing, etc. Why? How do they make your life easier?

Answer (score 6):

I can do 90% of my work with the following :

- [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for data
- [networkx](https://networkx.org/) for graphs
- [pulp](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/) for linear programming modeling
- [ipyleaflet](https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for interactive maps
- [line profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) for code profiling

I use them extensively because they are:

- used by many others
- well documented
- maintained
- user friendly
- free
- open source
- robust

Comment: +1, similar to my 90% list. I'd just add numpy for some specific tasks and flask, django or similar for web apps/requests to the models

Comment: @dhasson yes indeed! I think when you install pandas you get numpy for free :). I have little experience with web apps but have worked with flask once or twice and indeed it seemed great. And even though OP mentioned non solving librairies, I feel like the list is incomplete without ORTOOLS.

Comment: That's true, because pandas is built on top of numpy.

OR-Tools can be considered as more than a solving library, as it has a bit of pulp's capabilities and can be used as interface to many solvers. One of my remarks about its Python API is that performance can be way slower than using a low level language, see for example [the discussion here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1020) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joshlk/6e83d51d808ce30a74f1757d23bd15e5). Anyways, it's a great open source tool for prototyping models and developing solutions for reasonable scale instances.

Comment: I have also discoverd [osmnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/tree/master/notebooks) and am very impressed! very fun and very powerful!! built upon networkx and pandas so easy to manipulate. Incredible plotting. The only downside is that installing with pip is a nightmare for the moment.

Comment: osmnx is great! and installation can be cumbersome...you could check [this link](https://geoffboeing.com/2019/02/osmnx-docker-container/) there's a Docker image containing osmnx, jupyter, networkx, geopandas, pysal, matplotlib, among other useful libraries. Hopefully it'll contain or be compatible with the stuff you use for programming. [This link](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/tree/master/environments/docker) contains the details about the environment and requirements. Docker makes it easier to share code on projects between different machines in a way that's isolated and reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It works great with the docker :)